# C++ template function resolution in splitted namespaces

Tags: c++

Why compiler cannot resolve template function when it is declared in a following namespace?

work:

```cpp
namespace space {
template<> void f(T);
template<> void f(U);
}
void g() {f(U{});}
```

work:

```cpp
template<> void f(T);
void g() {f(U{});}
template<> void f(U);
```

not work:

```cpp
namespace space {
template<> void f(T);
}
void g() {f(U{});}
namespace space {
template<> void f(U);
}
```

work:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/U8tS3L1nkmGD9m7X

https://wandbox.org/permlink/dxmHD7SMz6uPdEHc

not work:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/FrEBMETzHD1KuHUx

and how to make the not working one work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (i.e, post the code not links and the posted code, for the working examples, should compile as-is).

Comment: *Don't* post links to code. Post code *in* the question *as text*.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as with any other function, at the time when you use a function, it has to be at least declared.

And because you moved your `g()` (in wich you call `f(U{})`) before definition `template<> void f(U);` and you don't have a declaration of it before your `g()`, it will result in a missing declaration error. So you at least need to have the declaration of the template function before the `g()`:

```
namespace space {
  template<> void f(T);
  template<> void f(U); // declaration
}

void g() {
  f(U{});
}

namespace space {
  template<> void f(U) { // definition
    // code
  }
}
```

In case of your real code:

```
// your first detail namespace
namespace detail {

   // […] the other template functions

   // the declaration of the two functions that are defined in the second detail namespace
   template <typename T, typename U>
   auto smart_division_impl(T a, U b, rank<1>) -> decltype(a * (U(1)/b));

   template <typename T, typename U>
   int smart_division_impl(T, U, rank<0>);

}
```

Comment: How to explain the case where namespace removed?